# How does hbase update or invalidate block cache?

Tags: caching, hbase

I am trying to understand the read and write paths of hbase. When an update of row is done via put command for a specific row, the data must be written to the memstore buffer. But let us say  for that key, there was an old value already present in block cache.

At this point a value X is present in block cache and new value Y is present in memstore buffer. If I execute a read command, I am getting Y. But isn't X the expected value? Because as per my understanding, whenever a read comes, block cache will be checked before memstore buffer.

Is my understanding wrong? Or is there any intermediate step where block cache gets updated or invalidated?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this interaction is missing in all the docs. As per my understanding, before updating memstore, if the block is present in the block cache it is invalidated, to avoid the case which you are highlighting.